# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeGuesser' not found

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.4, mftf

I am using Magento 2.3.4 and MFTF 2.6.3. I have setup the MFTF by

- setting environment credentials in `dev/test/acceptance/.env`
- running `vendor/bin/mftf build:project`
- running `vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests`

When I execute `vendor/bin mftf run:test AdminLoginTest` I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeGuesser' not found in root/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Allure/Event/AddUniqueAttachmentEvent.php:76
Stack trace:
/root/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Allure/Event/AddUniqueAttachmentEvent.php(43): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Allure\Event\AddUniqueAttachmentEvent-guessFileMimeType('/tmp/allure-att...')
/root/html/vendor/allure-framework/allure-php-api/src/Yandex/Allure/Adapter/Event/AddAttachmentEvent.php(35): Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Allure\Event\AddUniqueAttachmentEvent-getAttachmentFileName(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper), NULL)
/root/vendor/allure-framework/allure-php-api/src/Yandex/Allure/Adapter/Allure.php(116): Yandex\Allure\Adapter\Event\AddAttachmentEvent->process(Object(Ya in
/root/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Allure/Event/AddUniqueAttachmentEvent.php:76
```

Comment: What is your question? What did you execute? Did you install Magento using composer?

Comment: Hi Daniel,

I have install magento using composer, and created user credentials for backend. 
Configured details in MFTF .env File inside dev/test/acceptance folder.

I have run vendor/bin/mftf build:project and generate:tests commands.
when i execute vendor/bin mftf run:test AdminLoginTest 
i'm getting the above error in console: 

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeGuesser'

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/PHP-Fatal-error-Uncaught-Error-Class-Symfony-Component/m-p/458419/highlight/true#M15653

(Note: problem exists with PHP7.2 which is not recommended for Magento 2.3 - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#php)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the missing requirement of `symfony/http-foundation`. See https://github.com/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/issues/758 for more details.

Updating the MFTF to `^2.6.4` should solve your issue since they added `symfony/http-foundation` to the [composer.json](https://github.com/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/blob/2fe1372c35cecac41ec6ec4713a80988c7ee8a2d/composer.json#L30).

If you're running Magento <2.3.4 and an update is not possible you can downgrade to version `~2.4.5`.